# \vspace is not working between table caption and table

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I want some vertical space between the table caption and the table, and I am using `\vspace{3mm}`, which have always worked before. In this document however, the command works for some tables, for others it doesn't make any difference, and for some it even "crashes" the run, saying `Undefined control sequence [...] \vspace`.

An example of one of the table where the command makes no difference.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[mediumspace,mediumqspace,squaren]{SIunits}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

.
.
.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
            \caption{\label{tab:enzyme}Absorbance values from \textit{Fixed-time $\beta$-glucosidase assays}}.
            \vspace{5mm}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                C\textsubscript{substrate} (mM) & ABS (P\textsubscript{wt} 3x, 405 nm) & ABS (P\textsubscript{mut} 3x, 405 nm) \\ \hline
                10 & 0,959 & -0,312 \\
                5 & 1,023 & -0,268 \\
                1 & 0,913 & -0,234 \\
                0,1 & 0,304 & -0,231 \\
                0,01 & 0,042 & -0,237 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
```

Currently I have no table that fails the compilation. I had, but now it works without failing, however the command isn't making any difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, always check fully `Undefined control sequence` error messages: the most common cause of errors are typos like `\vpsace` that you had in the title. `;-)`

Comment: Have a look at the `caption` package- it's an excellent resource for this kind of thing

Answer (score 5):

there's a period outside of the braces at the end of the `\caption` line.  you can see it in the output, to the left of the table, if you look closely

that's starting a new paragraph, and while latex is in horizontal mode, the `\vspace` won't be acted on where you expect it to. remove the period, and all will be well.

this is a case where a blank line after the `\caption` line would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Chris, you can use `caption` package that provides `skip` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}
{
\captionsetup[table]{skip=50mm}     %% add this line, change 50mm to 5mm in your document
 \begin{table}[htb!]
            \centering
            \caption{\label{tab:enzyme}Absorbance values from \textit{Fixed-time $\beta$-glucosidase assays}}
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                C\textsubscript{substrate} (mM) & ABS (P\textsubscript{wt} 3x, 405 nm) & ABS (P\textsubscript{mut} 3x, 405 nm) \\ \hline
                10 & 0,959 & -0,312 \\
                5 & 1,023 & -0,268 \\
                1 & 0,913 & -0,234 \\
                0,1 & 0,304 & -0,231 \\
                0,01 & 0,042 & -0,237 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The period has to be removed anyway. Also there's a double vertical skip now. Remove `\vspace{5mm}`...

Comment: @karlkoeller Eh. I thought I removed them but no. Thanks and corrected.

Comment: you can also put the `captionsetup{...}` command inside the environment, for it to be locally scoped on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @ADP If that is the case, I would hook into `\AtBeginEnvironment`. But I left it simple without another package.